# Upload files to blob storage from azure webjob in parallel and get notified when ALL is done

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a folder with different folders named A, B and C on my azure website.

Each folder contains 10.000 images and I want to upload each folder to its own blob storage.

I would like to do this in parallel with 3 web jobs.

When ALL 3 web jobs are done **successfully** then and **ONLY** then I would like to start a 4th webjob.

How is this scenario done of starting a webjob aka buildstep... ONLY when the former webjobs aka buildsteps are successfully?

Comment: Is this a one time task, requiring only a nitty-gritty get 'er done solution, or is this part of an application where you need a solid solution that can be used over and over, with different parameters?

Comment: this is part of an application/deployment process which should be run 100 times a year.

Answer (score 0):

> When ALL 3 web jobs are done successfully then and ONLY then I would like to start a 4th webjob.

You could try this possible solution, in 3 uploading images webjobs, you could dynamically add/update queue message while webjob is done, for example, when one of these 3 webjobs uploaded all images, in webjob function you could check if there is a message is added in azure queue storage, if message not exists, you could add a message with 1 as message content, if message exists, you could [update the content message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues#change-the-contents-of-a-queued-message) to set message content as `queue message content value + 1`. And then in the fourth webjob, you could detect the message content and determine if do your task.

Comment: that would mean I have to execute every 10 seconds a polling function in job 4 where I check: queryMessageContent == 3 then continue with forth job. Is it not possible to order those webjobs???